# Why does re.findall return a list of tuples when my pattern only contains one group?

Tags: python, regex, findall

Say I have a string `s` containing letters and two delimiters `1` and `2`. I want to split the string in the following way:

- if a substring `t` falls between `1` and `2`, return `t`
- otherwise, return each character

So if `s = 'ab1cd2efg1hij2k'`, the expected output is `['a', 'b', 'cd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'hij', 'k']`.

I tried to use regular expressions:

```
import re
s = 'ab1cd2efg1hij2k'
re.findall( r'(1([a-z]+)2|[a-z])', s )

[('a', ''),
 ('b', ''),
 ('1cd2', 'cd'),
 ('e', ''),
 ('f', ''),
 ('g', ''),
 ('1hij2', 'hij'),
 ('k', '')]
```

From there i can do `[ x[x[-1]!=''] for x in re.findall( r'(1([a-z]+)2|[a-z])', s ) ]` to get my answer, but I still don't understand the output. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) says that `findall` returns a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. However, my pattern only contains one group. Any explanation is welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You pattern has two groups, the bigger group:

```
(1([a-z]+)2|[a-z])
```

and the second smaller group which is a *subset* of your first group:

```
([a-z]+)
```

Here is a solution that gives you the expected result although mind you, it is really ugly and there is probably a better way. I just can't figure it out:

```
import re
s = 'ab1cd2efg1hij2k'
a = re.findall( r'((?:1)([a-z]+)(?:2)|([a-z]))', s )
a = [tuple(j for j in i if j)[-1] for i in a]

>>> print a
['a', 'b', 'cd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'hij', 'k']
```

Comment: Your pattern is pretty odd. You don't need the non-capturing groups around `1` and `2`, or the group around the whole pattern (which you expend a bunch of effort to skip in the output). Instead, just accept that the `findall` call will return 2-tuples and turn them into single values with `a = [x or y for x, y in a]`.

Answer (score 8):

I am 5 years too late to the party, but I think I might have found an elegant solution to the re.findall() ugly tuple-ridden output with multiple capture groups.

In general, if you end up with an output which looks something like that:

```
[('pattern_1', '', ''), ('', 'pattern_2', ''), ('pattern_1', '', ''), ('', '', 'pattern_3')]
```

Then you can bring it into a flat list with this little trick:

```
["".join(x) for x in re.findall(all_patterns, iterable)]
```

The expected output will be like so:

```
['pattern_1', 'pattern_2', 'pattern_1', 'pattern_3']
```

It was tested on Python 3.7. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

Your regular expression has 2 groups, just look at the number of parenthesis you are using :). One group would be `([a-z]+)` and the other one `(1([a-z]+)2|[a-z])`. The key is that you can have groups inside other groups. So, if possible, you should build a regular expression with only one group, so that you don't have to post-process the result.

An example of regular expression with only one group would be:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'ab1cd2efg1hij2k'
>>> re.findall('((?<=1)[a-z]+(?=2)|[a-z])', s)
['a', 'b', 'cd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'hij', 'k']
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have an 'or' match without having the split into match groups just add a '?:' to the beginning of the 'or' match.

Without '?:'

```
re.findall('(test (word1|word2))', 'test word1')

Output:
[('test word1', 'word1')]
```

With '?:'

```
re.findall('(test (?:word1|word2))', 'test word1')

Output:
['test word1']
```

Further explanation: https://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/or-in-regex/

Comment: "non-capturing group" is the keyword here...

 (added solely for the  search engine)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this answer for similar question: https://bugs.python.org/issue6663
Just drop the parenthesis if you are using findall:

```
import re
s = 'ab1cd2efg1hij2k'
re.findall( r'(?<=1)[a-z]+(?=2)|[a-z]', s )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to make a simple change: *change the group to non-capturing group*

Code:

```
import re
s = 'ab1cd2efg1hij2k'
re.findall( r'(1(?:[a-z]+)2|[a-z])', s )
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', '1cd2', 'e', 'f', 'g', '1hij2', 'k']
```