# Grouping without creating new targets for re.findall()

Tags: python, regex, tuples

I would like to generalise [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593824/why-does-re-findall-return-a-list-of-tuples-when-my-pattern-only-contains-one-gr)
Is there a way to group elements that does not enlarge the re.findall() tuples?

My example:

```
line="(1 (2 (1 (1 (1 (2 You) (1 (2 (2 wo) (2 n't)) (2 (2 like) (2 Roger)))) (2 ,)) (2 but)) (2 (2 you) (3 (3 (2 will) (2 quickly)) (2 (2 recognize) (2 him))))) (2 .))\n"
numR=re.compile(r"\({1}(\d)? ((')*\w+|('|\.|,))\){1}")
re.findall(numR,line)
[('2', 'You', '', ''),
 ('2', 'wo', '', ''),
 ('2', 'like', '', ''),
 ('2', 'Roger', '', ''),
 ('2', ',', '', ','),
 ('2', 'but', '', ''),
 ('2', 'you', '', ''),
 ('2', 'will', '', ''),
 ('2', 'quickly', '', ''),
 ('2', 'recognize', '', ''),
 ('2', 'him', '', ''),
 ('2', '.', '', '.')]
```

As you see, the tuple contains 2 unnecessary elements at the end

Comment: You could use non-capturing groups using: `(?:...)` read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pattern you have 4 capturing groups. You could use a single alternation in the second capturing group having a total of just 2 capturing groups.

```
\((\d) ([.',]|\w+)\)
```

**Explanation**

- `\(` Match `(`
- `(\d)` Group 1, capture a single digit (use `\d+` for 1+ digits)
- `(` Group 2

  - `[.',]|\w+` Match one of the listed in the character class OR mat 1+ word characters
- `)` Close group 2
- `\)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VrCn3s/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Pi9hBK)

```
import re
line="(1 (2 (1 (1 (1 (2 You) (1 (2 (2 wo) (2 n't)) (2 (2 like) (2 Roger)))) (2 ,)) (2 but)) (2 (2 you) (3 (3 (2 will) (2 quickly)) (2 (2 recognize) (2 him))))) (2 .))\n"
numR=re.compile(r"\((\d) ([.',]|\w+)\)")
print(re.findall(numR,line))
```

Result

```
[('2', 'You'), ('2', 'wo'), ('2', 'like'), ('2', 'Roger'), ('2', ','), ('2', 'but'), ('2', 'you'), ('2', 'will'), ('2', 'quickly'), ('2', 'recognize'), ('2', 'him'), ('2', '.')]
```

Note that you can omit `{1}` and the alternation `('|\.|,)` can be written using a character class `[.',]`